# Files left after uninstallation of MS SQL Server

Tags: uninstall, sql-server

I just uninstalled MS SQL Server 2008 from my machine (using the "Uninstall or change a program" feature in Windows Control Panel). Now I notice that there's still a lot of files left. Around 1 GB actually.

When searching the web I found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882462.aspx

It is about SQL Server 2012, but I'm guessing 2008 had the same "feature"? The articles is basically a huge list of files that is left when you uninstall SQL Server to make it easier if you decide to re-install it.

Now I have two folders named "Microsoft SQL Server", one in "Program Files" and one in "Program Files (x86)". My question is can I delete these without having any problems arfterwards?

The article I linked to says that the files in the list can be deleted safely, but I don't want to go throught tat huge list of files and compare them with the files I have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft SQL server Program Files folders are safe to delete because you removed the program and thus anything left over is just for cached purposes by the installers or files that were modified and the uninstaller didnt remove them because sometimes you have custom settings inside .ini files that save certain info, its too much to explain lol but again it should be 100% safe to delete considering your circumstances. You havent mentioned if you installed SQL server for a requirement or just to try something, because if a different program installed SQL server for you it might have installed the express version that just installs a SQL instance and is required by other programs that use databases. But if this doesnt apply to you, you should be good.

Comment: No, this was the full version that I installed for testing during software development. I have now delete the folders. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

The link you provide has the answer right there for you..

"They are useful to the user and to Microsoft Customer Support, if the user decides to reinstall SQL Server. **Although these files are left after uninstall, the user may safely delete them from their system.**"

So yes, you can delete the files/folders.. if you arent using SQL server instances any longer.

Comment: Yes I read that, but it says that "these files" can be deleted, refering to the huge list. It doesn't say if that is all files in the folders I mention, and I'd rather not manually compare the list with the files I got... :/